# Flutter - SQFlite store and load image from database

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to save an image inside the sqflite database and the later on, I want to display it in a SliverAppBar as a background. Till now I am able to save the image(not sure if it is right, but throws no error XD):

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = directory.path;
File newImage = await _image.copy('$path/${recipeName.text}.png'); //_image already taken with image_picker plugin
String base64Encoded = base64Encode(newImage.readAsBytesSync());
```

And this String I am saving inside the database. But I also want to display. And as far I know, I have to get the String, but from now I on, I do not know anything how to get further. I have written a function to get the String, but do not know what I should do with this String. The function looks like this:

```
Future fetchRecipe(String name) async{
  var dbHelper = new DBHelper();
  Future<List<Recipes>> recipes = dbHelper.getSpecRecipe(name);
  return recipes;
}
```

The `getSpecRecipe(name)` points to this function:

```
Future<List<Recipes>> getSpecRecipe(String recipeName) async{
    List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE name = ?", [recipeName]);
    List<Recipes> recipes = new List();
    for(int i =0; i < list.length; i++){
      recipes.add(new Recipes(list[i]["id"], list[i]["name"], list[i]["definition"], list[i]["duration"], list[i]["favorite"], list[i]["timestamp"], list[i]["image"], list[i]["backgroundColor"]));      
    }   
    return recipes;
  }
```

It would be awesome, if somebody would be able to solve my problem. Thanks in advanceXD

Comment: You should save the image to the disk and save the file path string to the image in your SQL db. Then when you want to load the image you get the file path from the db and load the image from the disk.

Comment: Great idea. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

From the snippets provided, it seems that you're trying to save the image as a base64 on your database. And as mentioned by @Nordeast in the comments, it's better to save the image on the device's storage and store the file path instead. Also, given the snippets provided, it's difficult to replicate the behavior locally.